# How to implement can() method?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, frameworks

I'm now working with rbac yii2.
I defined all roles and permissions in database.
Now the question for me is where should I check access rule?
For example author just can update his own posts.
I saved rule in database too as rule_name = 'isAuthor'.
But I am confused about the check condition to access own posts.

Here is my actionRule:

```
<?php
public function actionRule(){
  $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
  $rule = new \app\rbac\AuthorRule;
  $auth->add($rule);

  $updateMobile = $auth->createPermission('mobile/update');

  // add the "updateOwnMobile" permission and associate the rule with it.
  $updateOwnMobile = $auth->createPermission('updateOwnMobile');
  $author = $auth->createPermission('author');
  $updateOwnMobile->description = 'Update own mobile';
  $updateOwnMobile->ruleName = $rule->name;
  $auth->add($updateOwnMobile);

  // "updateOwnMobile" will be used from "updatePost"
  $auth->addChild($updateOwnMobile, $updateMobile);

  // allow "author" to update their own posts
  $auth->addChild($author, $updateOwnMobile);
}
?>
```

Where and how can I implement that?
in Controller? behavior?
or other places?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the upated  for author own post the check (`can('author')` method )  should be placed in controller for two reason at least:

1. You should check not only if the use has role/permission  author  but also if the owner of the post is the user
2. Once check if the user can or not perform the related  code you must drive the correct response (render the update form if the user can or a access denied message if not)

These are tipically controller/action operations ..

These are just some first suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have a class (extending from `Yii\rbac\Rule`) associated with the rule. Then implement the `execute` function that checks whether the user is the author of the post and he has access to update the post.

Something like this:

```
class SiteRule extends Rule 
{

    //you can modify this to suit your needs. 
    public function execute($user, $item, $params)
    {
        //get user ie: \dektrium\user\models\User::findIdentity($user)
        //check if the $user is the author - using defined author or created-by       attribute in $params.
        //return true/false
    }
}
```

then in your controller/action you can use the `CheckAccess()` method (`yii\rbac\ManagerInterface`) to check if user has access:

```
 if(\yii::$app->user->can('author', ['post'=>\Yii::$app->request->post()(or your model]))  
 {//logic here}
```